# Firefox is not loading my scripts under Node.js

Tags: javascript, web, yeoman, gulp, yeoman-generator

I started a project using [generator-gulp-webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp) and I ran `bower install --save heatmap.js`. After that I added the Google Maps API source files to `index.html` and added the following two lines to the html-file:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/heatmap.js/src/heatmap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/heatmap.js/src/heatmap-gmaps.js"></script>
```

My problem now is that when I run `gulp serve`, none of those files are actually loaded. I don't seem to be getting any 404 errors when I look through the network inspector either. They seem to load just fine when I open up the `index.html`-file manually, without going through gulp / visiting `http://localhost:9000/`.

What am I missing here? I'm sure it's something really simple. [Here](https://gist.github.com/davorb/8f26becc8220080fb5c8) are all of the relevant files.

Comment: Is this a behavior restricted to Firefox ?

Comment: @Aperçu Yes. In Chrome I can see that it loads heatmap.js in the network tab, just fine. This is why I think that this is so weird.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, turns out that the answer is "have you tried disabling Adblock?".

Comment: Adblock disable *heatmap* ? Strange, *adblock plus* or *adblock*?

Comment: @Aperçu Adblock Edge.